# Maven project with javafx doesn't install because it 'cannot find symbol...' or 'package javafx. ... does not exist'

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I have run through all answers to the similar questions I could find here but none of them solved my problem. Therefore any suggestion is welcome.

I have a JavaFX project which builds without problems in Eclipse, but running

```
mvn install
```

causes multiple similar errors:

```
[ERROR] /home/slighten/Java/Projekty/Sample/src/application/CutSongFragment.java:[4,28] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Alert
location: package javafx.scene.control
[ERROR] /home/slighten/Java/Projekty/Sample/src/application/CutSongFragment.java:[5,34] package javafx.scene.control.Alert does not exist
[ERROR] /home/slighten/Java/Projekty/Sample/src/application/OpenCutDialog.java:[7,28] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class ButtonType
location: package javafx.scene.control
[ERROR] /home/slighten/Java/Projekty/Sample/src/application/OpenCutDialog.java:[8,28] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Dialog
location: package javafx.scene.control
[ERROR] /home/slighten/Java/Projekty/Sample/src/application/OpenCutDialog.java:[11,38] package javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar does not exist
[ERROR] /home/slighten/Java/Projekty/Sample/src/application/ChooseFile.java:[10,28] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Alert
location: package javafx.scene.control
...
```

The fragments of code which this output refers to are either imports such as

```
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
```

or instructions which refer to those imports like

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
```

My pom.xml contains both javafx-maven-plugin and jfxrt dependency:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>8.8.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>src/application/Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>javafx</groupId>
  <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
  <version>${java.version}</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <!-- Assuming there is jfxrt.jar file in {java.home}/lib  -->
  <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I have JDK 9.0.4 on my PC and openjfx installed.
Please feed me with some suggestions as I am running out of ideas after reading and trying so much options.

Comment: The `Alert`, `Dialog`, etc classes were introduced in JavaFX 8 update 40. So it looks like you may have a version earlier than that, which is being picked up by your runtime. The location for jfxrt.jar in the pom is an old location that was used by Oracle JDK prior to Java 8. Try logging `System.getProperty("javafx.version")` to see what it is finding. (Caveat: I don't use Maven to build JavaFX applications.)

Comment: Well, the command prints "9.0.4" which is my JDK version. How to understand this?

Comment: That's `javafx.version`, not `java.version`, right? I guess, then, that at compile time it is picking up the wrong version (since these are compile errors you are seeing). Not sure. This definitely looks like a version problem with JavaFX though.

Comment: Yes, that was javafx.version. So, presuming this is such version problem with JavaFX, what could I do?

Comment: Of course, that's when it is running, which presumably is not via Maven, since it's not compiling via Maven.... So I would see if you can figure out where Eclipse is pointing to for JavaFX (check the library paths), and where Maven is looking, and update Maven to be consistent with Eclipse. Just a strategy, I'm no Maven expert.

Comment: Thank you, I will google how to do it and give it a try.
Could you just give me a hand checking Eclipse library paths?
Meanwhile, somewhere in javafx.properties I have learned that javafx.runtime.version=2.2.40

Comment: Yeah 2.2.40 is way out of date. You won’t find `Alert` etc there. Right-click on your eclipse project and choose “Properties” and “Build Path”. I am away from my computer now but it is under there somewhere

Comment: Great thanks this far, but how to get the information on JavaFX location? The only thing I seem to see is 'JavaFX SDK' and no info about where it points to, maybe I'm searching in the wrong place?